# Nlog with windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nlog

I'm studying programming and as part of my project I have to use the system log.
I have therefore chosen NLog but I find myself confronted with a problem.

I followed the tutorial available on the official website of NLog ( [NLog documentation](http://nlog-project.org/2011/01/09/nlog-for-windows-phone-7.html) ) but when I start the project I get an error endpoint.

The complete error:
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5000/LogReceiver.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its trying to connect to another application running on your phone (localhost) on port 5000.  Likely there is no such aplication running. If you are running some log server on your machine, then you need to configure your phone app's nlog config to point to the ip address of your machine, or where ever the server is running.

Comment: Actually, I realized my mistake.
Before starting my application (windows phone 7) I have to start the server to be available at the reception of message.
Also, I noticed that port 5000 was not available so I withdraw to retrieve a random port.

Thank you for responding so quickly.